# Check if a video is unlisted on Youtube using Zend

Tags: zend-framework, youtube-api

Dear all,
I need to know if a video is unlisted through a Zend Framework query.
I know there is the read method isVideoPrivate() and the write methods setVideoPublic() and setVideoPrivate() but can't find anything about the unlisted state.
Can you help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was troubled at the same point,too.
But, I was able to distinguish "public" or "unlisted" by writing as follows.

```
$videostatus = $videoEntry->extensionElements[6]->extensionAttributes[permission][value];

if($videostatus == 'allowed'){
    $videostatus = 'public';
}elseif($videostatus == 'denied'){
    $videostatus = 'unlisted';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
try {
        //do stuff with the video
    }
    catch(Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        next;
    }
    catch(Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
        next;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't understand: I need to know if the video is in the UNLISTED state and can't find the method to look for it

Answer (score -1):

maybe try something like that

```
$permission = $video->extensionElements[5]->extensionAttributes['permission']['value'];
if ($permission == 'denied') {
    $state = 'unlisted';
} else if ($permission == 'allowed' || is_null($permission)) {
    $state = 'public';
}
```

if you doesn't get the right data on index 5 change to 6;